# Connection to wamp local server with DataGrip

Tags: mysql, wamp, datagrip

I'm trying to connect to my local MySQL server (wamp), but when I put all the information in datagrip it cannot create a connection.

[image: datagrip settings]

The database `tts` exists as is shown below:
[image: database existence]

Comment: the settings i've put on datagrip, and the existence of my local database

Comment: i don't know, see if something is wrong in the settings i've put

Comment: Can you connect to other databases on your localhost?

Comment: nope i tried them all and it doesn't work :/

Comment: How do you know that they work? Can you connect to to them from any other tool?